# Неправильная сортировка строк в PostgeSql

Tags: postgresql

Рассмотрим такой пример:

```
create table ttt (txt varchar(10));
insert into ttt values ('abc');
insert into ttt values ('a a');
insert into ttt values ('a z');
insert into ttt values ('a/a');
insert into ttt values ('a/z');

select * from ttt order by 1;
```

Результат как ни странно:

````
```
 txt
-----
 a a
 a/a
 abc
 a z
 a/z
```
````

Такое впечатление, что символы ' ' и '/' пропускаются при сортировке.
Замечу, что ascii у них меньше чем у букв (32 и 47), т.е. по идее они должны идти раньше.
Сначала я это замечал только относительно пробела, но сейчас возникла необходимость сортировать поля path для файлов (строить дерево папок)
и проблема, что называется, встала ребром.
Кодировка в базе UTF8.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как бороться?

Comment: *Такое впечатление, что символы ' ' и '/' пропускаются при сортировке.* Не пропускаются. Порядок сортировки определяет collation. [Поддержка правил сортировки](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/collation). В текущем collation их вес меньше... . См. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KukJ292Z).

Answer (score 5):

*нельзя просто так взять и отсортировать unicode*

> Замечу, что ascii у них меньше чем у букв (32 и 47), т.е. по идее они должны идти раньше.

Мысль замечательная, но оно так не работает. При том, это решает и делает вовсе не postgresql. Ваша операционная система эти строки будет сортировать точно так же:

```
melkij@melkij:~$ echo -e "a/z\nabc\na/b" | sort
a/b
abc
a/z
```

Потому что postgresql пользуется как раз системными правилами сортировки. Во множественном числе, да. Есть целая группа стандартов [одного только unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/), предписывающая как сортировать строки. Откуда процитирую,

> Collation is not code point (binary) order.

И что самое интересное, правила сортировки могут и действительно меняются со временем. Одни и те же строки в разных операционный системах или версиях libc могут сортироваться по-разному (что даже [даёт проблемы](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) для postgresql)

И далее уже продолжается поддержка разных collate со стороны postgresql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html

В частности, можно попросить использовать наиболее простую форму collate:

```
melkij=> select * from ttt order by txt collate "C";
 txt 
-----
 a a
 a z
 a/a
 a/z
 abc
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Так работает.

Comment: Добавлю, чтобы внести окончательную ясность в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, чтобы внести окончательную ясность в вопрос
Все-таки, см. https://simply.name/ru/pg-lc-collate.html
"linux просто **игнорирует** символы пробела, - и _ при сортировке"
и, видимо, еще некоторые другие не буквенно-цифровые символы.
Это видно на примере запроса (последние две строки):

```
select * from ttt order by txt;
 txt
-----
 /
 e
 r/
 re
 req
 r/z
```

Моя сортировка path сломалась именно на символе '/'.
Но с collate "С" все работает правильно - результат

```
select * from ttt order by txt collate "C";
 txt
-----
 /
 e
 r/
 r/z
 re
 req
```